# cannot load such file mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

I am  trying to use the ruby gem mechanize however, I continue 
     to get the error message cannot load such file mechanize.Any help would be highly appreciated. 
     Iam using ruby  version 2.3.0p0  with mechanize 2.7.5 and nokogiri 1.8.0

Comment: did you install it at all ? Does the current user have access to it, if it is installed already?  does it show when you do "gem list"?

Comment: Yes I have installed it all and I am able to view them all when I do gem list

Comment: How many versions of Ruby do you have installed? how are you managing your Rubies? Are you using RVM OR rbenv?

Comment: I am using cloud9 IDE for my programming

Comment: It does not look like `mechanize` is in you Gemfile. Add `mechanize` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.